# How can I associate a new entity with an existing entity in EF4?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4, associations, table-per-type

I've got a `Patient` entity (storing up-to-date information about a patient) and a `TreatmentPlanPatient` entity (a copy of a patient's date as it was when the "treatment plan", another entity not relevant to this question, was created):

[image: EF4 ORM model for my Patient entities]

I'm using Table-per-Type in this case. Now when I try to add a new `TreatmentPlanPatient` that's pointing to the `Patient` it was created from, EF4 actually does this:

1. It retrieves the existing patient from the database
2. Creates a copy of that patient
3. Assigns it a new ID GUID (despite StoreGeneratedPattern = None!)
4. Inserts the new patient into the `Patients` table
5. Rewrites the ID in my `TreatmentPlanPatient` instance to point to this new Patient
6. Inserts the new treatment plan patient in to the `TreatmentPlanPatients` table.

This is my code causing above behavior:

```
using(var container = new SmartTherapyContainer()) {

  // Look up the patient in the current container to make sure EF4 recognizes it
  var patient = container.Patients.First(r => r.Id == selectedPatient.Id);

  var treatmentPlanPatient = new TreatmentPlanPatient() {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    FirstName = patient.FirstName,
    LastName = patient.LastName,
    Street = patient.Street,
    ZipCode = patient.ZipCode,
    City = patient.City,
    BirthDate = patient.BirthDate,
    Telephone = patient.Telephone,
    Email = patient.Email,
    ClonedPatient = patient
  };

  // EF4 doesn't generate a separate .TreatmentPlanPatients collection :-/
  container.Patients.AddObject(treatmentPlanPatient);
  container.SaveChanges();

}
```

What is going on? How can I get EF4 to just insert a treatment plan patient into the `TreatmentPlanPatients` table and associate it with the existing patient in the `Patients` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do but according to your schema, the Patient table is a parent of TreatmentPlanPatients table (one to many relationship). Hence, you should add the TreatmentPlan to the Patient itself and not the Patients table. So rather than doing container.Patients.AddObject(treatmentPlanPatient), you should do patient.TreatmentPlanPatients.Add(treatmentPlanPatient). In this case, TreatmentPlanPatients should be a navigational property on the Patient table/entity.

OR, if you really want to use inheritance, then you have to use the same primary key (Id in this case) in both tables and have a one-to-one relationship.